# set Default.html as start page in Web application

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I had played down with my host configurations to the point that I can't revert back! I just want to be able to run it from my own visual studio, so I can debug some javascript and don't care if it is not running on Local IIS. I have web application in VS 2013 (**Proj1**) that I want to add a default.html page to. I set it as the start page, but when running the app, I keep getting the error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

Luckily, this is my own personal machine and I don't mind resetting its IIS or changing its apps configurations. I've tried the following:

1. I had initially setup my web application via VS as SSL Enabled = true, but now I am trying to reset, so my project properties look like this:
   [image]
2. Even though I don't care about IIS setup, I still looked into my C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config file, but looked fine
   [image]
3. looked at my web.config, but nothing stands out
   [image]

I think the process of setting up the SSL is the culprit. Is there anywhere else I should look? I just want to be able to run a simple Default.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem very similar to this before in the past. This is what I did to solve it.

1. Try to debug a very basic page with nothing on it (Make sure that works)
2. Then start building the page back up.
3. For me it was when I added "Custom Controls" back in, when I removed those controls from the page everything worked.